# Temporary valide ipa

Tags: ios, provisioning, ios-provisioning, ipa

I'd like to send an ipa to a prospect client so he can see what we are doing, but I don't want him to show our demo to all our competitors.

Do you know if there is a way to build an .ipa that would only work for a few days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "timebomb" your app by checking the date on startup and just showing an alert if the date has passed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was hoping an easier solution exists. I Hope I'll not have problem with date and localization (the client is in japan)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

But you can validate yourself. The simplest way would be to check the current date. But the client can change the date on his device easily.

Or you could put a file on a webserver that tells the app if it's allowed to run or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may "phone home": require a request to a Web Server which tells the app if it's allowed to run.

That means your app wouldn't be usable in offline mode, but it's acceptable for a demo. This also means you can track how many times the prospect opened your app, and block invalid UDIDs if a competitor got the app and resigns it to install it on their devices.